# Devel Generate keeps generating files after uninstalling it

Tags: debugging

Some time ago I removed Devel from my site because it is in production now. However, when I look at the Content list I still see files being generated, like generateImage_J4d7CV.png and nq3cv2oMx9.txt

I tried to reinstall and deinstall Devel from scratch, that didn't solve it.
A Google search on the issue rendered no solution either.

What could I do to prevent further generation of useless files?

Edit: I noticed that files are being generated when the layout is saved of a content type.

Comment: Core is able to generate these sample files without Devel. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21ImageItem.php/function/ImageItem%3A%3AgenerateSampleValue.  It's unlikely, though, that Devel or any other module generates samples outside of tests and without someone triggering it. Please tell more how to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit this is not Devel then, this is the Layout Builder using sample content for the preview. These are marked as temporary and should be deleted by cron after the time configured here:

```
/admin/config/media/file-system
```

Comment: I think you're right, when checking the files the images are temporary. However the generated txt files are permanent. So this could be a bug?

Comment: It's not so easy to locate the second file because the name consists only of a hash. If it's a bug it should be in one of the field types configured in the content type.

Comment: Yes, the .txt files are one of the field types, so it could be